# What does "perimeter of application" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I've come across this term repeatedly in a paper I'm reading and from the context, I'm not sure what it means.

Context:

> The building of a proper  dataset from the available
>   internal/external data  requires that a bank develop policies and
>   procedures to address its several features (ie 
>   **perimeter of application**, observation period, reference date, de minimis modelling thresholds  and data treatment).

Comment: I'm guessing, but it could mean the [**scope**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28project_management%29) of the project. For a bank, that may include reference to internal 'Chinese Walls'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might have a technical meaning within a particular field that I’m not aware of.

However, just using the words in their common meanings:

**Perimeter**

> The outermost parts or boundary of an area or object

**Application**

> Practical use or relevance

In this sense, *perimeter of application* would define the area inside which something is useful. Outside this area the thing would not be applicable.

Answer (score 2):

In software applications, defining the "project perimeter" gives to stakeholders a shared understanding of the project and of its objectives.

The "project perimeter" specifies the project boundaries and covers all deliverables. As the deliverables (documentation and software) may change during project lifecycle, it is important to specify right from the start what is in the scope of the project and what features are not covered.